# Не могу зайти в GitHub в Intellij Idea

Tags: intellij-idea, github, jetbrains

Захожу в Intellij Idea, чтобы войти с ее помощью на Github. Перехожу в Settings нажимаю на Add Account
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Меня переносит на страницу Jetbrains, где я зарегистрирован
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

потом нажимаю на Authorize in Github. Меня перенаправляет на страницу:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И все, на кнопку Authorize JetBrains я не могу нажать.
В Intellij Idea аккаунт не добавился.
Подскажите что делать?

Comment: не пользоваться JetBrains